# How to stop the state variable to be overwritten from previous value in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

i am storing the data got from server in a state variable. It works fine if i open items having large data display correct information. however after opening item with no data available for it displays previous item value.

consider the scenario,

item 1 has no data, item2 has large data.
open item1 displays no data for it. 
now open item2 displays data for it (which is large)
now open item1 displays item2 data instead of showing no data.

Not sure where i am going wrong.

Below is the code,

```
class ItemDetails extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        item_info: null,
        item_info_loading: false,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.unmount = new Promise((resolve) => { this.on_unmount = 
        resolve;});
        this.load_item_info();
        this.unlisten_path_change = this.props.history.listen((location) => 
            {this.handle_path_change(location.pathname);});
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevProps.item_id !== this.props.item_id) {
            this.setState({item_info: null}, this.load_item_info);}
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
       if(nextProps.item_id !== this.props.item_id) {
            this.setState({item_info: null}, this.load_item_info);
       }}

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.on_unmount();
        this.unlisten_path_change();
    }

    load_item_info = () => {
    const file_name = 'item_info.json';
    this.setState({item_info_loading: true});
    client.get_item_file(this.props.model_id, file_name, 'json', 
    this.unmount).finally(() => this.setState({item_info_loading: false}))
        .then((request) => {
            this.setState({item_info: request.response})
        })};

    render () {
       <ItemInfoTool
           item_info={state.item_info}
           item_info_loading={this.state.item_info_loading}/>}}

    export default class ItemInfoTool extends React.Component {
        state = {
            open_item_data: null,};

        componentDidMount() { 
            this.set_open_item_data();
        }
       componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
           if (prevProps.selected_id !== this.props.selected_id) {
               this.set_open_item_data();
           }
       }

set_open_item_data = () => {
    if (!this.props.item_info) {
        return;
    }
    if (this.props.selected_id === this.empty_id) {
        this.setState({open_item_data: null});
        return;
    }

    let open_item_data = {
        info: [],
        values: [],
    };
    const item_info = this.props.item_info;
    for (let i=0, ii=item_info.length; i < ii; i++) {
        if (item_info[i].somekey.includes(this.props.selected_id)) {
            const info = item_info[i].info;
            const values = object_info[i].values;
            open_item_data = {
                info: typeof info === 'string' ? info.split('\r\n') : [],
                values: values ? values : [],
            };
            break;
        }
    }
    this.setState({open_item_data:open_item_data);
};}


export function get_item_file(item_id, file_name, response_type, 
on_progress, cancel) {
     const local_override_defined = item_files[item_id] && 
         item_files[item_id][file_name];
         if (local_override_defined) {
             const file = item_files[item_id][file_name];
             const reader = new FileReader();

             return new Promise(resolve => {
                if (response_type === 'blob') {
                    resolve({response: file});
                } else {
                    reader.onload = () => {
                        if (response_type === 'json') {
                            resolve({response: JSON.parse(reader.result)});
                        } else {
                            resolve({response: reader.result});
                        }};
                reader.readAsText(file);}});}

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        item_file_get_url(item_id, file_name).then(({response}) => {
            const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                 request.addEventListener('progress', on_progress);
                 request.open('GET', response.url);
                 request.responseType = response_type;
                 send_request(request, undefined, cancel, 
                 response.url).then(resolve).catch(reject);})});}
```

Could someone help me solve it. Thanks. i doubt there is some asynchronous requests happening.

Answer (score -1):

You need to clear data while closing operation